# What would be the most painless way of installing Windows 10 in dual boot with preinstalled Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, grub

I'm using Arch Linux.

My current setup looks like this:

```
02:29:59 [luken@Luken-Desktop: 0] ~ 
(1:501)$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    1   477G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    1   512M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    1    40G  0 part /run/media/luken/b2b5b237-9897-4fb8-8228-d
├─sda3        8:3    1  11,5G  0 part 
└─sda4        8:4    1   425G  0 part /run/media/luken/0d3832e7-8dd4-4207-a595-6
sdb           8:16   1 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   1 465,8G  0 part /run/media/luken/Storage
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    60G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 867,5G  0 part /home
```

I'm currently NOT using UEFI:

```
02:39:57 [luken@Luken-Desktop: 0] ~ 
(1:501)$ [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
BIOS
```

Do I need to perform some additional configuration steps to enable it before that?

I'm using GRUB.

I would like to install Windows 10 in dual boot, on a completely different SSD. I can do whatever I want to prepare for this, like backing up Grub's config etc. This Linux system is my workstation so it's critical for the operation to be as painless as possible.

I'm pretty sure it should be pretty simple, assuming preparing live usb and such, but because I cannot afford losing access to my Linux system for too long, could someone with experience list all the steps that are needed for configuring this dual boot? There seems to be different paths for that, and I'm a bit confused.

One more thing:
In the past I had a peculiar setup, where I was selecting OS by simply going to BIOS and choosing bootable device when I needed. Would that be the simplest solution? I just don't remember if it required any further configuration than installing Windows on a separate drive. But it would also suit me, if it would be the simplest solution.

Comment: The most painless way to dual boot would be to use two separate disks. Disconnect the one you are not installing to while installing the OS. Worst case scenario you have to use the bios boot menu to switch OS if grub can't find or identify Windows.

Comment: install widows ... shrink windows partition ... install linux in the unused disk space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporarily disconnect all other disks for the time of installation of Windows 10: otherwise, Windows 10 has been known to be unpredictable in deciding where it will install its bootloader. And no, even the "advanced mode" of the Windows installer won't give you a chance to explicitly choose where to install the Windows bootloader.

Since you're not currently using UEFI, that means you must boot the Windows 10 installer legacy-style if you wish GRUB to be able to incorporate the Windows installation into its menu. The Windows installer will choose the boot method of the new OS to match how the installer itself was booted. If you can accept selecting the OS by BIOS settings only, then you can choose whichever boot method you wish for Windows 10.

By selecting legacy-style boot for Windows 10, you'll also be restricted to using MBR partitioning on the Windows 10 system disk - the Windows installer ties together the selection of boot method and the partitioning type, so there will be only two options:

- legacy BIOS/MBR boot and MBR partitioning
- native UEFI boot and GPT partitioning

The MBR partitioning has a pretty firm maximum limit of about 2 TiB, so if you expect the Windows 10 installation to be a long-lived one, you might wish to pick the UEFI boot method for it.

Also, the UEFI specification has built-in provisions for multiple operating systems and bootloaders coexisting in the same system: with the Windows 10's "self-healing" features, dual-booting it might actually be easier using the UEFI boot method than with MBR. Just remember to leave the UEFI NVRAM boot variable `Boot0000` for Windows, and you'll be fine. (Assuming that your system's UEFI firmware does not have bad bugs...)